# How do you override the existing Sass with your own styles in Materialize?

Tags: sass, materialize

When working with Sass for Materialize and wanting to add my own `.scss` code to a project is it a better practice to directly modify the existing `.scss` files within the project, or to create your own separate `.scss` files, compile them to a different .css and refer to it at a later point in an HTML file to override the existing styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest **never** overwrite the classes of any library's `.css` or `.sccs` file if you are using some library like **materialize** or **bootstrap**.

Always create your own custom classes and use your CSS to modify the layout. Use your own CSS selectors while writing classes.